# how to add product to cart include size and quantity php

Tags: php

I wanna add a product to cart with chosen size and quantity. I've written this codes but my questions are:
 first of , does it work safely and correctly?
and then if user add one specific product(product_id) twice to cart(in two different request) how can I add the quantities of both requests?
and finally how should I handle different sizes for one product id?

```
if (isset($_POST['add2cart'])){
    if (is_numeric($_POST['proId']) and is_numeric($_POST['count']) and ($_POST['count'])>0 and strlen($_POST['size'])<5) {
        $proId= $_POST['proId'];
        $proCount = $_POST['count'];
        $proSize = $_POST['size'];
        if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
            $_SESSION['cart'] = array('id'=>$proId, 'count'=>$proCount, 'size'=>$proSize);
            $_SESSION['cartStatus'] = 'open';
            $successMsg = 'با موفقیت به کارت اضافه شد .';
        } else {
            if (isset($_SESSION['cartStatus']) and $_SESSION['cartStatus'] == 'open') {
                $_SESSION['cart'][] = ['id'=>$proId, 'count'=>$proCount, 'size'=>$proSize];

                $successMsg = 'با موفقیت به کارت اضافه شد .';

            } else {
                $errorMsg = 'یک عملیات خرید در جریان است . تا پایان این خرید ،سبد قفل است.';
            }
        }
    }else{
        $errorMsg = 'خطایی در اطلاعات ورودی رخ داده است.';
    }

}
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question. `i'm not sure` is not a question. What does this code, what should it do, does it throw any errors?

Comment: Regarding the comment above, please review [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on making your question clear and easy for others to answer.

Comment: Try this: `$_SESSION['cart'] = array(array('id'=>$proId, 'count'=>$proCount, 'size'=>$proSize));`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you have missed one array level in your `$_SESSION['cart']` array.  Try this:

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = array(array('id'=>$proId, 'count'=>$proCount, 'size'=>$proSize));
```

However your if statement would make more sense IMO if it was like this (without else part):

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = []; //declare an empty array
    $_SESSION['cartStatus'] = 'open';
    $successMsg = 'با موفقیت به کارت اضافه شد .';
}
// Check for both $_SESSION['cart'] and $_SESSION['cartStatus']. Use && instead of "and"
if (isset($_SESSION['cartStatus'], $_SESSION['cart']) && $_SESSION['cartStatus'] == 'open') {
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = ['id' => $proId, 'count' => $proCount, 'size' => $proSize];

    $successMsg = 'با موفقیت به کارت اضافه شد .';
} else {
    $errorMsg = 'یک عملیات خرید در جریان است . تا پایان این خرید ،سبد قفل است.';
}
```